# How to detect if `read-event` or `y-or-n-p` is running?

Tags: events, timers

In `haskell-doc-mode` we have a timer that shows useful tips in minibuffer when cursor is idle for a moment. In other part of Haskell Mode there is code asking questions using `y-or-n-p` or `read-event`. The problem is `haskell-doc-mode` does not know about this and overwrites echo area. Users are confused and think Emacs is hanging.

Is there a general mechanism to detect if `read-event` or `y-or-n-p` is running?

Link to the reported issue:

https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/820

Comment: At the linked issue, is was claimed an hour ago that the issue has been fixed.

Comment: The fix there is suboptimal. We are looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best method seems to be found in `eldoc` that also displays temporary info in minibuffer:

```
;; Decide whether now is a good time to display a message.
(defun eldoc-display-message-p ()
  (and (eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p)
       ;; If this-command is non-nil while running via an idle
       ;; timer, we're still in the middle of executing a command,
       ;; e.g. a query-replace where it would be annoying to
       ;; overwrite the echo area.
       (not this-command)
       (eldoc--message-command-p last-command)))
```

Specifically `(not this-command)` ensures that no user command is running and that solves the problem in question.

Comment: Great! I'll add this to my bag of tricks.

Answer (score 1):

For `y-or-n-p`, you could check the value of `input-method-use-echo-area`. It is turned on by `read-key-sequence`, which is indirectly used by `y-or-n-p` – and quite likely by various other commands you'd like to treat the same way.

Detecting an active `read-event` seems to be harder. Perhaps it's preferable to call it via a wrapper which rebinds some variable to let you detect its use.

Comment: Gracjan's answer is so much better, perhaps I should delete this one. But as it not utterly wrong, just incomplete, it doesn't seem quite right to do so. It's like rewriting history.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could check the return value of `current-message`.

IIRC you can use the haskell-doc.el by enabling `eldoc-mode` instead of `haskell-doc-mode` (at least that worked for me at some point), so maybe an alternative solution is to deprecate `haskell-doc-mode` and rely on `eldoc-mode` (which is enabled by default in Emacs-25) instead.